# Dynamically draw marker on last point in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to draw a marker on the last point. Data source is dynamic.
Have a look at following code

```
$(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var l = chart.series[0].points.length;
        var p = chart.series[0].points[l - 1];
        p.marker = {
            symbol: 'square',
            fillColor: "#A0F",
            lineColor: "A0F0",
            radius: 5
        };
        a = 1;
        chart.series[0].points[l - 1] = p;
        chart.redraw(false);

    });



    var ix = 13;
    var a = 0;

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        ix++;
                        var vv = 500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 40);
                        chart.series[0].data[0].remove();
                        var v;
                        if (a == 1) v = {
                            y: vv,
                            x: ix,
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'square',
                                fillColor: "#A0F",
                                lineColor: "A0F0",
                                radius: 5
                            }
                        }
                        else v = {
                            y: vv,
                            x: ix
                        }

                        a = 0;

                        series.addPoint(v);
                    }, 1500);
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {}
        },

        series: [{
            data: [500, 510, 540, 537, 510, 540, 537, 500, 510, 540, 537, 510, 540, 537]}]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zNUP/

On button click event I am trying to draw marker on last point which is already added to chart.

Is there a way to do that??

Comment: If any answer helped, please vote/mark it accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 $("#btn").click(function() {
    var l = chart.series[0].points.length;
    var p = chart.series[0].points[l - 1];
    p.update({
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square',
            fillColor: "#A0F",
            lineColor: "A0F0",
            radius: 5
        }
    });
    a = 1;

});
```

solution @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/zJZSx/

Also tidied up your code a little, removed the removal of point before adding one at the end, highcharts supports it inbuilt with the third param to addPoint as true, which denotes shift series, which removes first point and then adds the given point.

I didn't really understand what the a vv etc were, but well i didn't bother much either. I think this is enough based on what you asked for.

Comment: Note to folks trying to do this - should you be enabling dataGrouping for your series, THIS WILL NOT WORK.  Silently, it will fail.  Endlessly, it will taunt you.  Only works if dataGrouping is false.

Comment: @Irongaze.com: Now if you do this with dataGrouping enabled it will give you a JS console error message: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/24