# Highcharts manipulate with points on the graph

Tags: svg, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to access each point's on the graph actual svg object in order to change some of its properties on-the fly.

Say I have 100 objects, of those around 50% need to be drawn in a different color (though they belong to the same data series, no way round). Thus, by using:

```
chart.series[0].points
```

I'm able to modify object properties (like fill) but no way to redraw the chart afterwards. Using chart.redraw() gives nothing, well actually it changes the points color but only after I mouse over them, the chart itself is not redrawn properly.

Any help appreciated.

Regards!

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Have you tried `chart.redraw();`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways that you can use here.

**On Load**
You can define a color for each of the points explicitly while adding them to the data array. The following is what the documentation states

> A list of object with named values. In this case the objects are point configuration objects as seen below.
>
> Range series values are given by low and high.
> Example:

```
data: [{
name: 'Point 1',
color: '#00FF00',
y: 0
}, {
name: 'Point 2',
color: '#FF00FF',
y: 5
}]
```

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/mXPPH/

**Dynamically**
You can add the color/markers to individual points using the `point.update()` method as follows,

```
var p = chart.series[0].points[l - 1];
p.update({
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square',
        fillColor: "#A0F",
        lineColor: "A0F0",
        radius: 5
    }
});
```

Reference : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update%28%29

You may also want to look a similar answer I had provided for this question @ [Dynamically draw marker on last point in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083794/draw-marker-on-last-point-in-highcharts/11785236#11785236) and its jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/zJZSx/